# SSL libraries in program

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I am quite new to Delphi.  My problem is with a email application.  I am unable to connect to the email server as the computer could not load the ssl libraries.  What procedures do you need to follow to add the ssl libraries to the program folder?  I have scoured the net in search for an answer to no avail.

This question is different to the "Delphi+TidHTTP" in the sense that the advice given there did not help.  Could you please advise on a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to be clear as to what libraries you use. Indy perhaps? Which version? And this is documented, so the best solution is for you to find the docs and read them well.

Comment: I am using Indy 10 with Delphi 2010.  I will add a sample of the code

Comment: Actually perhaps I'm wrong. It seems that Indy docs are hard to find. I seem to remember that this is a project with disdain for documentation. You probably already have searched fruitlessly. Sorry. So far as I know you download the latest ssl DLLs from the fulgan mirrors and put them in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: Delphi 2010 is quite old, many things in Indy have changed. The current version can be used with Delphi 2010, so if you encounter any errors I suggest to use the current 10.6.x release. Package installation is not required if you just add the Indy paths to the project search path.

Comment: You're asking how to put files in a folder? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I was also unable to add the code.  This is a school project.  This means that I cannot use updated components as the computers (with limited user rights) will be unable to understand the component.  When I try to connect using the TidSMTP component.  But this yields a "could not load ssl library error".  I have tried to add the newest ssleay.dll and libeay.dll to the project folder (ver. 1.0.2).  My question is actually more in the line of how to link these updated libraries to the project?